# polymer drop-down selected item changed

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

```
<paper-dropdown-menu>
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selectedEmployee}}" attr-for-selected="id">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employees}}">
      <paper-item id="[[item.id]]">[[item.name]]</paper-item>
    </template> 
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

When I change the `employees` array in the above code with new array, **the drop-down list reflects the new value of employee names**. But the currently selected employee still shows the old value for the name property.

Tried triggering the name property still did not take effect.

```
this.notifyPath('selectedEmployee.name', selectedEmployee.name);
```

Tried clearing the entire property and setting again, did not help.

```
this.set('selectedEmployee', null);
this.set('selectedEmployee', employees[1].id); //new selected employee instance with different name
```

`paper-dropdown-menu` selected item changed looks for the text in the selected `paper-item` which on debug shows the old name.

How do I trigger the selected label to be repainted ?